# Render Excel Chart in WPF application

Tags: wpf, tfs, wpf-controls

I have created couple of TFS Report in Excel by right clicking a query (Bugs query) and selecting "Create report in Microsoft excel" option. By doing this it has created a Graph.

I want to embed this Graph in WPF application.

As this is a dynamic report which will change in time as the numbers of bugs gets fixed during the day graph will change.

So it it possible for me to **integrate a TFS report graph in to WPF application**?

Comment: Is integrating Excel within your WPF application an option? Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Yes integrating Excel within your WPF application is an option and i am using Excel 2010

Comment: Could you not just recreate the graph in a WPF compatible graphing library by connecting to the cube, warehouse and or collection database?

Answer (score 0):

In essence you are asking how to embed excel in a wpf application like mentioned on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Embedding_Excel.aspx.

However, using the reports and/or filling the wpf graphs using the tfs oom will be a lot faster to build an easier to maintain. It might even be wiser to just drop it on the SharePoint server (if it runs excel services) and serving it from the browser (instead of a wpf app) or as a dasboard.